# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /home4/beunique/public_html/wp-content/plugins/hello.php:69

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() in
> /home4/beunique/public_html/wp-content/plugins/hello.php:69

What is this please any help would be great. I am getting a critical error on the website and cannot access even the back end. thanks

I am unsure how to sort this out any help I would gratly appreciate it

Comment: What part of the error message is confusing you? The error means that on line 69 of hello.php, the code tried to call a function named `add_action()`, but in fact there is no such function in that PHP script (or in any of the scripts included/required by that script). This could be caused either by a typo, or a misconfiguration where the PHP file which contains this function isn't included in the hello.php script, or just that you simply haven't written that function yet.

Comment: This appears to come from the "Hello Dolly" plugin, https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/hello.php But there is no reason why the core WP function `add_action` should not be available in there, if this file was used within the WP context (and not called directly on its own.) You can try and remove or disable this specific plugin - but I would not be surprised, if you would keep on getting the same error from other places then.

Comment: I restored website but went down again, I THINK i HAVE BOTS THAT ARE MAKING IT GO DOWN, AYONE KNOW HOW TO STOP THIS

Comment: You mean you think something is modifying the files or data on the server without your permission? If  so then please read [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server). P.S. Please don't SHOUT at us, it's really not necessary :-)

Comment: Hi yes sorry for shouting hehe, I have restored the website and added an extra bot blocker, I currently have wordfence! It seemed when uploading tiktok videos I was getting a serge of robots heading to my website and it was affecting my speed and causing it to go down. Do any of you know if I can add some code into the background to stop this in the future please? Just about to start my computer science degree so hopefully I will know this stuff soon ;)

Comment: I don't have enough info about the precise nature of the problem to really advise on it specifically, sorry.